# Oracle-Nested and Joins

Tags: oracle

Problem Statement

Write a query to display the shipment_entity details that are being shipped to the port 'Chennai' or 'Cochin'. Display the records sorted in ascending order based on the  id.

Expected Output

```
select se.id, 
       se.name, 
       se.contact_first_name,  
       se.contact_last_name, 
       se.identification_number, 
       se.credit_limit, 
       se.is_active,s 
       e.address_id
from shipment_entity se, 
       shipment s, 
       port p 
inner join shipment s on se.id = s.shipment_entity_id 
inner join port p on s.departure_port_id=p.id  
where p.name in ('Chennai','Cochin');
```

SQL ERROR:

> inner join shipment s on se.id = s.shipment_entity_id
>                            *
>   ERROR at line 3: ORA-00904: "SE"."ID": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have combined the pre-ANSI 92 syntax with the explicit join syntax. You only need to include the tables once in the FROM clause:

```
...
from shipment_entity se
     inner join shipment s on se.id = s.shipment_entity_id 
     inner join port p on s.departure_port_id=p.id 
where ...
```

Incidentally, you will make your own life easier - as well as those of anybody else who reads your code - if you learn to use spacing and line breaks to make the layout clearer. This is not being fussy: readability is a feature our code needs, because it makes maintenance and debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ,shipment s,port p

```
select se.id,se.name,se.contact_first_name,se.contact_last_name,se.identification_number,se.credit_limit,se.is_active,se.address_id
from shipment_entity se ##### you need to remove this-> ,shipment s,port p 
inner join shipment s on se.id = s.shipment_entity_id 
inner join port p on s.departure_port_id=p.id where p.name in ('Chennai','Cochin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using both conventional oracle and ansi-syntax. When using conventional syntax you do not need explicit `"JOIN"` and `"ON"` clause . Similarly if you are using Ansi-syntax you should not give all the tables in `FROM` clause.

Please try any of the below queries:

Conventional:

```
select se.id, 
       se.name, 
       se.contact_first_name,  
       se.contact_last_name, 
       se.identification_number, 
       se.credit_limit, 
       se.is_active,s 
       e.address_id
from shipment_entity se, 
       shipment s, 
       port p 
where  se.id = s.shipment_entity_id 
and s.departure_port_id=p.id  
and  p.name in ('Chennai','Cochin');
```

ANSI:

```
select se.id, 
       se.name, 
       se.contact_first_name,  
       se.contact_last_name, 
       se.identification_number, 
       se.credit_limit, 
       se.is_active,s 
       e.address_id
from shipment_entity se
join  shipment s
on  se.id = s.shipment_entity_id 
join port p 
on s.departure_port_id=p.id  
where p.name in ('Chennai','Cochin');
```